# How can I make the text of a TextView use the style I give it?

Tags: android, text, textview, styles

In Android on a `TextView`, how can I make the text `▶ Play` use the style that I give it. The problem is with the text `▶`. On the emulator it displays fine, however when testing on a device it appears blue with white text.

The following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".TestingActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="▶ Play"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Produces:

[image: Screenshot]

And:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".TestingActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:text="▶ Play"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Produces:

[image]

Comment: have you tried using vectors drawables instead of using a plain text to show play icon ?

Comment: @Umair Using vector drawables, images, etc. all seems completely overkill when all I want to do is make the text on a `TextView` simply use the style I give it.

Comment: in your case I believe android is counting play icon as emoji that's why it's being displayed like that and blue background has something to do with your application theme. I just copied this in my code and it is showing just fine but with black play button.

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution for you...
Just use `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/your_icon"` in your textview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".TestingActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/your_icon"
        android:text="Play"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can drawableStart to set an icon before text in Textview
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/play_button_icon"
    android:text="Play"/>

 To download icon use : https://materialdesignicons.com/
```